# Javascript passing variable on as null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I honestly can't think of a better title, I'm new with writing my own javascript.

Basically, I have the following script which will translate a `hex` value to an `rgb` value:

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
    function hex2rgb(hex) {
        if (hex.length < 3) {
            $(".result").text("Error");
        }
        if (hex[0] == "#") {
            hex = hex.substr(1);
        }
        if (hex.length == 3) {
            var temp = hex;
            hex = '';
            temp = /^([a-f0-9])([a-f0-9])([a-f0-9])$/i.exec(temp).slice(1);
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) hex += temp[i] + temp[i];
        }
        var triplets = /^([a-f0-9]{2})([a-f0-9]{2})([a-f0-9]{2})$/i.exec(hex).slice(1);
        return {
            red: parseInt(triplets[0], 16),
            green: parseInt(triplets[1], 16),
            blue: parseInt(triplets[2], 16)
        }
    }
    var hex = $(".hex").val();
    var rgb = hex2rgb("#" + hex);
    $(".result").text("rgba(" + rgb.red + "," + rgb.green + "," + rgb.blue + ",1)");
});​
```

<sub>Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/JkeKV/5/</sub>

When the number of digits entered in the textbox is less than 3 (an incomplete `hex` code), it changes the text of `.result` to error. The code itself works fine, but the console is throwing up an error saying...

> TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating
>   '/^([a-f0-9]{2})([a-f0-9]{2})([a-f0-9]{2})$/i.exec(hex).slice')

I assumed that if the code was less than 3 digits, it would just display the error, not try to move on to `if (hex.length == 3) {}` function, which it seems like it is doing. Is any of this correct?

Also, would it be better to use `if (hex.length == 3) {}` or `if (hex.length >= 3) {` for the function that translates the `hex` to `rgb`? I'm only thinking this because the number of digits has to be `3 >= x <= 6`?

Comment: why you checking for length == 3?  just error if Hex length < 6

Comment: Because the hex length could be 3, `#333` would be the same as `#333333`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *will* move to the next `if` statement because you are not `return`ing from the function when there's an error:

```
if (hex.length < 3) {
  $(".result").text("Error");
  return;
}
```

An alternative is to use an `else` for the rest of your code that *does* pass that validation:

```
if (hex.length < 3) {
  $(".result").text("Error");
} else {
  if (hex[0] == "#") {
    // ...
}
```

With respect to your other question, I'd use `if (hex.length >= 3 && hex.length <= 6) {}` since as you said, you want to validate that `3 >= x <= 6`.

Comment: It looks like it's moving on again from there, as I'm getting this error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'rgb.red')`. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/JkeKV/6/

Comment: @Charlie: What input are you using? Do you accept #ffffff, or just #fff? Your regular expression only considers the former.

Comment: I thought I was accepting both, I'm trying to figure out why I did that. Oh, I think I figured it out... It should be `if (hex.length == 3) {}` so that if it's 3 or more, it gets passed into the function, but if it's 6, it gets passed into the triplets function?

Comment: @Charlie: Since you now do not return an object with the `red` property. You need to take that into account after invoking the `hex2rgb` function. Also, why do you always concatenate the `#` character if you remove it in the function?

Comment: @Charlie: Here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/JkeKV/7/. I think it's what you want. Please let me know if you need some help understanding anything.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. As I said, this is the first real JS utility that I wrote, and a lot of it is code that I found from various websites, so it didn't come together perfectly. I think an example of that is linking the pound sign even after it's been removed. Was my original code somewhat good?

Comment: @Charlie: Yes, despite the additional pound which was making your comparisons a little more harder to understand (since it made the original string have an extra character).

Comment: Awesome. One more question (if you don't mind answering): is it possible to check to see if a keyword is in an array, and if it's not, to display a different error message? Would I have to do the same thing with using an `else` statement so that if it it's in the array, it doesn't keep running through the code?

Comment: It is, yes. Suppose your array is `["word1", "word2"]` and is called `arr`. To check if a given string is within it, use `arr.indexOf("your_string") != -1`. Yes use another `else if` to validate this *extra* condition, and keep the `else` part of the code as it is currently.

Comment: Okay, so a basic example of this would be: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/7DnD8/1/ Is there any way to not have it be case sensative though?

Comment: OH, figured it out: `$("input").val().toLowerCase()` Is that a good way to do it? Then all the array objects would be lowercase?

Comment: Hi, yes, or convert the array to upper case, and use `toUpperCase()`, it's the same, really: http://jsfiddle.net/7DnD8/2/ :)